# Ubicación de botones en base de datos

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

En c# estoy haciendo un POS, y los permisos que tengo en la BD permiten o no cierta función.

Mis preguntas son:

- ¿Cómo debo guardar esos botones en la BD y cómo los coloco en el form?
- ¿Cómo guardo la configuración del POS o la ubicación de cada botón en base de datos (es conveniente que haga eso)?
- En caso de guardar la configuración en BD, ¿tendría problemas de resolución?

Comment: que es un POS ? a que cierta funcion te refieres cuando dices que lo permite o no la db ?

Comment: guardar botones ? lo que guardas son datos no controles

Comment: se trata de una aplicacion winforms, no ?

Comment: un POS es un punto de ventas amigo, y si winform para guardar la mejor configuraion de la vista, ya que existen distintas resolucions y tamaño de pantalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que intentas persistir son coordenadas o sea el `Location` de cada control no lo persistas en la db o si lo haces que no sea cada valor individual porque sera complejo

Podrias serializar a xml o json una clase que definas para asignar a esta los valores de posicionamiento de cada control

Entonces puedes definir una clase como ser

```
public class ControlLocation
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
}


public class ControllocationList : List<ControlLocation>
{
    public void AddLocation(Control ctrl)
    {
        this.Add(new ControlLocation() { Name = ctrl.Name, X = ctrl.Location.X, Y = ctrl.Location.Y })
    }

    public string GetXmlSerialization()
    {
        //aqui seralizas a xml el objeto
    }
}
```

la idea es que ya sea que persistas el xml o json en un archivo o si lo haces en la db que sea un unico campo como texto donde guardas el xml con toda la info de posicionamiento de controles

A la clase podrias agregarla la funcionalidad en donde le pases un string del xml y deserialice para obtener la info para trabajarla nuevamente

Creo que la idea se entiende, si vas a persistir configuracon compleja ue sea una estructura unica y no cada dato individual en la db, porque crear eso en datos de tabla y armar los queries es mas complejo que serializar y deserializar una estructura

Nota: en el ejemplo no use el Point como dato de propiedad porque no estoy seguro si se comporta correctamente al serializar

Answer (score 1):

lo que debes hacer es vincular los botones a los roles, en el caso de WPF seria generar un binding al `Visibility` del botón si el usuario conectado tiene cierto rol. en el caso de Windows form es el mismo concepto pero me parece que tendrías que desarrollar la implementación

[Wpf esta respuesta contiene ejemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019204/how-to-manipulate-wpf-gui-based-on-user-roles)